# What happens to a spark applications requesting more memory than than the cluster has?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, livy

If there is a spark cluster with worker nodes of say `x GB` memory, and there are 5 such worker nodes what would happen to a applicaion if:

```
1. Driver memory requested in the application is > x GB

2. Driver Memory + Executor Memory * Number of executor requested in the application is > 5x GB
```

Also, if the application does not get accepted at Yarn, does livy queue flushes it or it says in the queue?

Comment: Usually spark initializes a cluster client and start submitting the application after this client makes sure that there are enough resources available in the cluster. So I think none of your circumstances can be submitted successfully.

Comment: And any driver/executor process can not extend beyond a worker node? (So there is limit on the driver/executor memory size which is max. the worker node memory)

Comment: You are right, and for some resources management framework like Apache Yarn, you need to set a similar maximum limit of resource unit.